# ¿Cómo pasar datos de blade a JS?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Hola con todos quisiera saber si existe una forma de concatenar o pasar los variables de mi blade a js, el problema surge es que tengo un boton que genera un bloque de un formulario que por defecto ya existe uno en el blade es decir en el boton de añadir se genera un segundo bloque de formulario por medio de javascript el problema es que en el primer bloque tengo selects que trae dato de mi bd y datos php para almacenar y al generar el segundo bloque los selects no se generan como debieran si no como texto.

BLOQUE POR DEFECTO QUE SE CARGA EN EL BLADE:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

BLOQUE GENERADO POR EL JS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia el segundo bloque generado solo lo toma como texto.
Este es un fracmento del codigo js que uso para la generacion del bloque.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. El código va como texto para que otros puedan leer correctamente y replicar tus errores. Naide va a responder con imágenes para ponerte a transcribir. Por favor ve a [edit] tu pregunta

Comment: si desea trabaja puro JavaScript, le recomiendo vue , en lavare se puede implementa fácilmente

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar una variable de php a JS se puede utilizar esto:

```
   let myvar = "<?= $myPhpVar ?>"
```